# android tv how to add read more button to the content details layout

Tags: android

https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback

Android tv leanback, how can I add the button 'read more' in the content details layout where the sinopsys of the movie is very long.

Comment: Please make your Question more clear with your requirement.

Comment: In this android tv example project https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback, there is a viewHolder DetailsDescriptionPresenter that extends AbstractDetailsDescriptionPresenter with title and body. I need to ovverride this layout adding a button 'read more' like the official google movie android tv app

Comment: Could you post the screen shot so that i can suggest you something.

Comment: I think Rayna is referring to the button on just below synopsis as can be seen in Google Movies & TV app. Clicking it cause the description view to animate and expand to full screen. Ryana, were you able to fix it?

Comment: how about adding an action, on click set selected position to 1